# Merge two files by conditionally overriding parts of second file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, diff

I have two config files, old and new. New is a template config with default values and maybe additional variables. Old is modified config with values that have to be preserved. I need to make a new modified config:

1. if variable exists in both old and new version, keep old value
2. if variable is commented out in old, keep it so and vice versa
3. if variable exists only in old, delete it
4. if variable exists only in new, keep it

old modified

```
$ cat old.cfg
# var1 = 111
# var2 = 123
var3 = 111
var4 = 123
var5 = 123
```

new default config

```
$ cat new_default.cfg
var1 = 111
# var2 = 123
var3 = 111
# var4 = 111
var6 = 111
```

new modified config (desired)

```
$ cat new.cfg
# var1 = 111
# var2 = 123
var3 = 111
var4 = 123
var6 = 111
```

`#` is always separated with a whitespace (since config editing is manual, Im using `sed` for this: `sed -i -E 's/^#([^ ])/# \1/'`), so maybe awk can be used for the whole thing. For now I have this `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}!a[$1]' new_default.cfg old.cfg`  that is writing down the variable name (1st column in awk), that is common for both files.

===================================================

UPD:
Finally I have used the answer below and modified it so it's now better serving my needs and also looks uglier.

1. accepting two arguments, old config and template for the patched config
2. assuring there is a following space after `#` at the beginning of the line
3. assuring every `=` is surrounded by one space each side
4. assuring every actual comment starts with two `#` instead of one
5. issuing awk command: if line starts with `#` -> compare second column; 
   starts with `##` -> compare the whole line; starts without `#` -> compare first 
   column

.

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    cp $var $var.bak
    sed -i -E 's/^#([^ ])/# \1/' $var
    sed -i -E 's/(.?)(\s?)=(\s?)(.?)/\1 = \4/' $var
    sed -i -E 's/^#([^=]+)$/##\1/' $var
done
awk '{if(/^# /)k=$2;else if(/^## /)k=$0;else k=$1;}NR==FNR{a[k]=$0; next} 
{print (k in a)?a[k]:$0}' $1 $2 > output.txt
```

Comment: I also do apologise aforehead if this is a duplicate or if I have not made it clear. Stayed on the website in read-only mode for years, but today got completely confused with sed, awk, diff, patch and so on (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk       '{k=/^#/?$2:$1} 
     NR==FNR {a[k]=$0; next}
             {print (k in a)?a[k]:$0}' config.old config.new

# var1 = 111
# var2 = 123
var3 = 111
var4 = 123
var6 = 111
```

not sure all tests are covered in your sample input/output though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement a merge with application-specific logic, the only sure way to get the logic you want is to actually build it yourself. Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A old new

read_to_array() {
  local line
  local -n dest=$1
  local -n comment_dest=$2
  declare -g -A "$1" "$2"
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
      "")          continue;;
      "#"*" = "*)  line=${line#"#"};
                   comment_dest[${line%%" = "*}]=$line;;
      "#"*)        continue;;
      *" = "*)     dest[${line%%" = "*}]=${line#*" = "};;
      *)           echo "Ignoring unrecognized line: $line" >&2
    esac
  done
}

read_to_array old old_comments <old.txt
read_to_array new new_comments <new.txt
declare -A done=( )

for key in "${!new[@]}"; do
  # if commented out in old, leave it that way
  if [[ ${old_comments[$key]} ]]; then
    echo "#$key = ${new[$key]}"
    continue
  fi
  # key exists in both old and new; use old
  if [[ ${old[$key]} ]]; then
    echo "$key = ${old[$key]}"
    continue
  fi
  # key is only in new; keep it
  echo "$key = ${new[$key]}"
done

for key in "${!new_comments[@]}"; do
  # if present at all in old, we were already emitted
  [[ ${old[$key]} ]] && continue
  echo "${new_comments[$key]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes you always have spaces around `#` and `=`, as in your sample input:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {if ($1 == "#") new_ignore[$2]; else new[$1] = $3; next }
    $1 == "#" { delete new[$2]; print; next }
    { old[$1] }
    $1 in new || $1 in new_ignore { print; next }
    END { for (key in new) if (!(key in old)) printf "%s = %s\n", key, new[key] }
' new_default.cfg old.cfg
```

```
# var1 = 111
# var2 = 123
var3 = 111
var4 = 123
var6 = 111
```

Comment: Wow guys, you rock! This is absolutely awesome input from all of you, highly appreciated!